# Can't connect to mysql on OS X

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I have installed `mysql` with Homebrew and I just can't access it.

When I run `mysql -uroot`, it says, I can't access. So I though maybe there was a password set. So I deleted `/usr/local/var/mysql` and ran `mysqld --initialize`. This output, besides other things:

```
A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: randomPassword
```

So I tried `mysql -uroot -p'randomPassword'. But this still doesn't work. What is my password? I may have installed`mysql` with Homebrew before that, but I can't imagine that the old password is still saved somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience of MacOS installs. In my experience of Linux installs, it prompts for the user to enter a root password on install.

There are however a wealth of instructions around on how to reset the root password if not known. I have used the `--skip-grant-tables` method many times.

- Stop the MySQL server
- Restart it with `--skip-grant-tables`
- Open up the `mysql` command line client
- `mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
- `mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';` for MySQL 5.7.6 and later, or
- `mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');` for MySQL 5.7.5 and earlier

Source:
[MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: I think somehow `launchctl` (OS X's `initd`) somehow kept the password. This worked for me, thank you.